# Programming bind in js

Tags: javascript

I have decided to recreate [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) as `binding` in order to exercise. Woefully, I have encountered some problems and can't understand the reason of `undefined` output.
Here is my code:

```js
var alex = {
  firstname: "alex",
  surname: "surname",
}
let nameyourself = function() {
  console.log(`${this.firstname} ${this.surname}`);
}


Function.prototype.binding = function(smth, ...params) {
  smth.__proto__.bindedfunct = this;

  return smth.bindedfunct;

}
nameyourself.binding(alex)();
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is `binding` supposed to do?

Comment: does the same as bind in js

Comment: Yeah it...isn't.

Comment: just not to have the same name

Comment: You just end up calling `(nameyourself)()`, which resets `this` to `undefined` and `alex` isn't being passed to anything.

Comment: But I passed alex via smth

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. I changed `this.name` to `this.firstname` also for clarity, otherwise you get the automatically generated ID of the window for the snippet. Since that's irrelevant to discuss, I just renamed the property to focus on your issue.

Comment: A proper implementation does not need to fiddle around with `smth.__proto__.bindedfunct = this;`

Comment: `smth` is `alex`. You assign `nameyouyself` to a property on `alex.__proto__`. You then return that which you assigned. For all intents and purposes, `binding` just does `return this` with the side effect of adding a property to `alex`' `__proto__`. That doesn't "bind" anything.

Comment: `smth.__proto__.bindedfunct`? I've no idea what `.bindedfunct` could be...? Why not `Object.setPrototypeOf(alex, bindedfunct)`?

Comment: @zer00ne An arbitrarily named property to hold the… "binded function"…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more detailed explanation is given beneath the example code.

```js
const alex = {
  firstname: "Alex",
  surname: "Surname",
}

function nameYourself(...args) {
  console.log(`${this.firstname} ${this.surname}`);
  console.log('args : ', args);
}

Function.prototype.binding = function(target, ...boundArgs) {

  // the function to be bound.
  const boundFunction = this;

  // the binding wrapper-function.
  return function (...args) {
  
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply
    boundFunction.apply(target, [...boundArgs, ...args])
  }
}

nameYourself.binding(alex, 'Hello')(alex.firstname, alex.surname);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Since the custom `bind` functionality `binding` should be implemented via `Function.prototype` it will be called itself as a method of every function object. Thus, a `binding`'s `this` context will be a function.

The latter then shall be executed within a custom `this` context. For the OP's example this context is intended to be the `target` object `alex`.

In order to achieve the OP's task the `binding` implementation needs to return a wrapper function that inside its function body does delegate the bound function to the `target` object via a functions [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `binding` doesn't do what you expect. You're just returning the function you pass it.

In order to achieve a similar functionality as `bind` you need to use `Function.prototype.call/apply` to call the function with a *thisBinding*.

Here's a sample implementation using `.apply`;

```js
var alex={
    name:"alex",
    surname:"surname",
}
let nameyourself = function(){
   console.log(`${this.name} ${this.surname}`);
}

Function.prototype.binding = function (thisBinding, ...args) {
    return (..._args) => {
        this.apply(thisBinding, [...args, ..._args]);
    }
}

nameyourself.binding(alex)()
```